# I'm trying to connect with my Heroku app and when I enter my email and password, it's asking me "Enter the code generated by your authenticator app."

Tags: authentication, heroku, verification

I'm pulling up the authentication app and typing the code on Heroku app but it says"verification code is not correct" so I'm assuming the authentication app somehow doesn't connect with the Heroku. So, how do I change the authentication app without get into the account?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "how do I change the authentication app without get into the account?"—you can't, that's the whole point of MFA. Contact Heroku support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem. I try to recover my  own account by email support account-lockout@heroku.com and not recived a answer yet

The time to change the method was until last April 28

Here u can find more information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mfa-sms

> Users who currently rely on SMS as an MFA verification method can continue to use this option till April 28, 2022.
> The option to use SMS text messages as an MFA verification method is not available for new users.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I am using the salesforce authenticator app on an android device, and here is how I solved the issue.

go to app settings, find the salesforce authenticator app, tap on (Force stop), clear the app cache, reopen the app, go to the Heroku login page, and try to log in with the generated code by the app. hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue until I was told that awhile back, Heroku stopped with the free accounts and you have to purchse, at least, the $5 dyno account.

https://www.heroku.com/dynos

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34379136)